# Automatic returning of value of a property of a type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my new job, they have a paradigm where they have thousands of properties of objects that are a type of, say, Long.  But this is called a LongField.  And to get the actual value of that field, I have to use property.AsLong.  I'd love to just type property and not have to add the .AsLong or .AsInteger or .AsBoolean, etc.

Is there any way that I can edit the base class(es) to allow me to just use property and not property.AsWhatever?

EDIT: for example code, here is what I mean.

```
Dim asdf as Long = myThing.thingsID
```

That shows an error: "Value of type 'LongField' cannot be converted to 'Long'"

I'd prefer to not have to remember if I'm dealing with a Long or a LongField, and then have to add .AsLong to everything.  Same with ints, bools, dates, etc.

Comment: It sounds like this paradigm is well established and the team is quite comfortable with it the way it is. If it concerns you, you should raise the issue to the team and solve with them. You might find a solution here, but without buy-in from the team, changing their paradigm will not bode well for you. "Seek first to understand..."

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Not of thousands properties, but at least one.

Comment: @madreflection, I agree, I would not and will not just toss in some random code that would upset anyone.  I'm just hoping I can bring something that will make all of our lives easier.

Comment: Well, I'd first establish that *their* lives *need* to be made easier (and if not, maybe this isn't the right job for you). But I'm with GSerg... I'd like to see an example because it's extremely difficult to provide solutions without specifics. There are things that I might suggest and then find it it doesn't fit your situation because you didn't provide enough information to rule it out. And without those specifics, the question is too broad.

Comment: And the reason I suggest establishing that first is that just bringing a solution out of nowhere may torque some of the team members and make it harder to get traction on it. This is probably better discussed on the Workplace stack, but it's not entirely unrelated here.

Comment: There's a LongField class and it has an AsLong property?

Comment: Wait, this is VB code. Why is C# tagged? Ha... like I said, something I might suggest could be ruled out... by the fact that VB wouldn't even support it!

Comment: @madreflection I tagged C# because there is also C# in the solution.  I'm personally doing both in this job.  And, yes, again, I would never introduce anything that would upset anyone else.  I just know from past experience that sometimes people get complacent and maybe the pain point isn't high enough for them to investigate a solution for it.  But if I bring one, they may love it.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville yes, exactly.

Comment: Complacency can be a real problem. I feel ya. I believe VB supports implicit conversion opeators, same as C#, so your `LongField` could implicitly be converted to `Long`, and the C# code would work the same.  The problem with implicit conversions is that the inverse needs to be explicit, and the proper implicit/explicit directions (as made far clearer with VB's `Narrowing` and `Widening` keywords, one of the few cases where VB's verbosity is quite good) is usually the *reverse* of what makes this convenient.

Comment: To put that more plainly, `Long` -> `LongField` is widening so it should be *implicit*, whereas `LongField` -> `Long` is narrowing so it should be *explicit*. Again, the reverse of what would be convenient.

Comment: @madreflection, okay, I'm going to do research on what you mean by that.  I pretty much get it, but there are a TON of implications of that that I'll have to figure out.

Comment: If you're editing the base classes, why not just another property of the correct type that directly reads/sets the property.AsWhatever()?  Although, in my mind, not sure that really does much but add noise.

Comment: What are these types? Sounds like they are classes that wrap structures. I wonder whether it's been done this way because these people have an issue with the behaviour of value types.

Comment: If a `LongField` exists solely to wrap a `Long` and it will always have a value - maybe these types were created to supports nulls before nullable value types existed - then you could certainly implement the `CType` operator in the class and make it a widening conversion from `LongField` to `Long` so it can be done implicitly. That would not break any existing code but it would allow you to get or set such a property using a `Long` value. That would kind of defeat the purpose of those types though, I would think.

Comment: My guess is that the class was introduced to enforce some serialization rule. Perhaps it overrides .ToString() or something like that

Answer (score 1):

If you have a type like this:

```vb
Public Class LongField

    Private value As Long

    Public Sub New(value As Long)
        Me.value = value
    End Sub

    Public Function ToLong() As Long
        Return value
    End Function

End Class
```

then the last two lines of the following code are not allowed, even with `Option Strict Off`:

```vb
Dim l As Long = 123
Dim lf As New LongField(456)

l = lf
lf = l
```

If you add the following code to that type though:

```vb
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(source As LongField) As Long
    Return source.value
End Operator

Public Shared Widening Operator CType(source As Long) As LongField
    Return New LongField(source)
End Operator
```

both those lines become legal and will perform implicit conversions, even with `Option Strict On`.

This would allow any existing code to continue to work as is and for that `ToLong` method to continue to be used in new code, while also allowing a `LongField` object to be treated as though it were a `Long`, for the purposes of getting and setting at least. It is still a class though, so is subject to reference type semantics rather than value type semantics. It's hard to say whether this would defeat the original purpose of such a type because it's hard to know what that purpose would have been exactly.

It's worth noting that this:

```vb
someObject.SomeLongFieldProperty = someLong
```

would result in that property referring to a new object of type `LongField`. It may be that, the way things are currently implemented, you're actually supposed to change the `Long` value within the same `LongField` object. We can't tell from what you've provided. That said, if that was supposed to be the case then it couldn't have been guaranteed unless the property was `ReadOnly` anyway.